# Display Form Depending on the value of a field in another form

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have two forms on the same page, but I want the second form to be displayed only if a certain field in the first form is greater that four. How can I achieve this using JavaScript? I'm using Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to do this in Django. Expanding on [T. Stone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026531/display-form-depending-on-the-value-of-a-field-in-another-form/2026564#2026564), something like this jQuery should work:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#some-field").change(function () {
    var currentVal = parseInt($(this).val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 4) {
      $('#form2').show();
    }
    else {
      $('#form2').hide();
    }
  })
  .change();
});
</script>
```

You'll want to mark `form2` as hidden initially.

Comment: This is the correct method, as I had mis-interpreted what the OP was asking for.

Comment: I've now added code to hide the form if the value fails the test.